# Having problems how to use an if statement to determine if something is in a list or not. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that takes a blank input and does various things with it. The input "show me contact _____" (With the ____ being filled in with somebody's name). The names are stored in a list and I need it to be able to check if the name is in the list, and if it is, print the contact information.  I figured an if statement would be the best way to do it, but I cannot figure out how.

Edit: I have tried using *in*, but my problem is that the input contains "show me contact _____" and not just the name.  This causes this:

```
names = ['john doe','john doe','john doe']
user_input = input('>')
if user_input in names:
    print(email)
```

to not work.

Comment: `if user_input in names:` ;)

Comment: `if user_input == `?

Comment: When dealing with user input, you may also want to clean it up a bit: `user_input = input('...').strip().lower()`

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
if user_input in names:
```

When used with a list, `in` checks for membership. When used with a string, it will check for substrings.

Comment: Or better still, `if user_input in set(names):`. Set should be made beforehand for it to make sense.

Comment: A `set` is only (really) useful if you plan to do several queries or you can initialize it directly as set (`names = {'john doe','john doe','john doe'}`).